# PHPbb - Enable bbcodes on a 'custom' page?

Tags: php, external, bbcode, phpbb

I've set up a custom, an external page, in my phpbb forum and are using PHP to get threads from the announcement section to show up. However, the BBCode made in the forum isnt being parsed, this is my code and what I tried after hours of googling: **(BBCode -> HTML attempt)**

https://hastebin.com/pusoxisevi.xml

this is the output im getting:

```
let's see if identifiers or just trash for stylings

[list][*][/*:m][/list:u]
[code][/code]
[quote][/quote]
```

I've tried with custom made parses too, but all seems to give the same non-formatted output. Is there a way to enable bbcode for external pages, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!!

**Edit**

I tried this `

```
    // Parse BBCode to HTML
    $bbcode = new bbcode(base64_encode($bbcode_bitfield));         
    $bbcode->bbcode_second_pass($post_text, $r['bbcode_uid'], $r['bbcode_bitfield']);
    $post_text = smiley_text($post_text);


    // ASSIGNMENT
    $template->assign_block_vars('announcement_topics', array(
                 'TOPIC_TITLE'         => $T,
                 'TOPIC_CONTENT'       => censor_text($post_text),
          ));
}`
```

but output is still the same..

Answer (score 0):

fixed it,
need to **Of course** select the bitfield and uid from database or theres nothing to parse........